# How to achieve the smoother indeterminate progressbar used in Gmail's Android app

Tags: android, progress-bar

I see a difference between the normal Indeterminate ProgressBar of Android and Gmail's Indeterminate ProgressBar

any ideas about how did they achieve such smooth indeterminate Progressbar?

[image: Gmail uses very smooth progressbar]

Comment: Try using Chris Bane's ActionBarPullToRefresh. Link here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Comment: Tried ActionBarPullToRefresh but it uses the native indeterminate progress bar after pull event. I am looking for the smoother indeterminate progress bar used in Gmail. their version of Indeterminate animation is much different and smoother.

Comment: I'm writing a blog post about this. I'll let you know when I release it ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hey I wrote a post/lib about that.

Blog post: http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/11/12/make-your-progressbar-more-smooth/

Library: https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Sample app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.sample

Go check it out ;)

**EDIT**: if you want to reproduce exactly the gmail's progressbar, [here is the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/kitkat-release/src/com/android/mail/ui/ButteryProgressBar.java)

Comment: @TusharPandey yea, you have to port it by yourself or use a fork.